# Turning 4 for-loops into one

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, calculator

I was wondering if I could get some help or tips to make this for loop more complex. Instead of it having 3 different loops i'm trying to make them into one. I cant seem to fix it, i've tried googleing and fixing it on my own. If you could have a look at it I would be very thankful.

//noob programmer

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        row[1].add(button[i]);
    row[1].add(button[14]);
    add(row[1]);


    for(int i = 4; i < 8; i++)
        row[2].add(button[i]);
    row[2].add(button[15]);
    add(row[2]);

    for(int i = 8; i < 12; i++)
        row[3].add(button[i]);
    row[3].add(button[16]);
    add(row[3]);
    row[4].add(button[18]);

    for(int i = 12; i < 14; i++)
        row[4].add(button[i]);
    row[4].add(button[17]);
    add(row[4]);
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about improving working code belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Andreas this looks like example code and lacks concrete context. It would be off-topic on Code Review and would get closed there rather fast.

Comment: @Andreas- going along with what Zeta's sentiment: It is okay to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the order actually matters, I think you need at least two loops; something like,

```
row[4].add(button[18]);
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    int ndx = 1 + (i / 4);
    row[ndx].add(button[i]);
}
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    row[i].add(button[13 + i]);
    add(row[i]);
}
```

should be equivalent (all buttons added in the same order to a row and with all the rows added).

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
    for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
        for (int i = 4 * r; i < 4 * r + 4; i++)
            row[r + 1].add(button[i]);
        row[r + 1].add(button[r + 14]);
        add(row[r + 1]);
    }
```

obviously this is missing `row[4].add(button[18]);` but that looks spurious anyway.

Comment: Because the fourth loop only counts to 14, not 16, and because of that spurious `button[18]`, the question is only asking to combine the first three loops, not all four. That's my guess anyway.

Comment: Each for-loop is for every row on a calculator (I have 4 rows) And I saw my question was wrong so I edited that one.